# How to ignore branch coverage for missing 'else'

Tags: unit-testing, istanbul

Is it possible to ignore the marker `E` in istanbul branch coverage?

I am using Jasmine+karma+Istanbul. Is there any possibility to ingore `E` and get 100% branch coverage?

*Maybe a property that can be set in config?*

Here is an example of the coverage results
[image: example of the error]

Answer (score 40):

You can use `/* istanbul ignore else*/` just before the `if` statement to ignore the missing `else`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `/* istanbul ignore else */` to tell istanbul not to include that in the coverage.

```
/* istanbul ignore else */
if (props.onChange) {
    props.onChange(event);
}
```

Comment: How to do this for each file, is there any global setting available?

Comment: Same question for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the comments all over the place you can also set up another test where you actually hit that else.

If you have something like this:

```
_method: function () {
  if (this.foo === 'foo') {
    this.bar = false
  }
}
```

You just need to create a test where `this.foo` does not equal `'foo`'.

Comment: yes, thanks.. but in some cases it's seems difficult to create a test ( i.e. promise catch(e) ..if  { validation error.. } else { next(e) }. the else block is picking up any other kind of error and passing them to the next middleware error handler...  appreciate any link to it